# Using Titles in Germany?

Tags: titles

I was wondering what is the correct use of titles in Germany as I am so confused by it all.

My English title is: Mr X HNCert, CertHe, FdSc, AMRSB, Mem.R.E.S, FIScT, FSABM.

Would my German Title be: Herr Bakk. rer. nat. mult. X HNCert, CertHe, FdSc, AMRSB, Mem.R.E.S, FIScT, FSAMB

I am going to work for six months in Germany and was wondering of the correct way to do things. S

Comment: Why do you want to translate all of these? What is the context?

Comment: I am going to work for six months in Darmstadt, I am a Biochemist/Microbiologist with a specialism in Mycology

Comment: @user73451 This is not what Thomas asked, I believe. It is irrelevant what your title is where you live or the translation of that title. Why is it so important? Does it make any difference if you just go with Mr X?

Comment: @padawan I know from experience that titles matter in Germany. No it does not make a difference to me.

Comment: Seems like you might need someone who recognizes those titles to translate 'em.  What do they stand for?

Comment: @Nat HNCert is a Higher National Certificate in Applied Biology, CertHe is a Certificate in Higher Education in Biochemistry, FdSc is a Foundation Degree in Science specializing in Applied Microbiology and the other letters are memberships of different organisations/societies

Comment: And you really take two minutes to introduce yourself in your language and assume everyone to know all these terms? I don't see no "Prof" and no "Dr" in there, so you are Mr. X in Germany. :)

Comment: "titles matter in Germany" ... not from my experience.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, these are **not titles**.

**The only academic titles that are used in Germany in writing or conversation are Dr.** (also Dr.-Ing.) **and Prof.** (sometimes MSc and more rarely BSc and also there has been Dipl. which, of course, is still in use).

No one would ever use certificates or memberships in their name. This would look extremely strange in Germany. Also, one usually does not introduce yourself as "Dr. X" or "Prof. X" (you may want to use these on letters or emails signatures, though).

Comment: I've also seen Dipl.-Ing. / DI (Diplom-Ingenieur) used, in writing at least. I think a useful rule of thumb might be "if it takes less than five years to earn, nobody cares" :).

Comment: Right, these are postnomials